# Android - Access static file on Django server using Glide fails

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework, android-glide, filenotfoundexception

I have the following `Django` model :

```
class MyAccount(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    profile_picture = models.FileField(upload_to='Images/',default='Images/placeholder.jpg')
    ...
```

When the user creates this account, he gets a default placeholder image. The registration of the user ( creation of the `MyAccount` instance for a particular user) works as expected.

But my Android App can not get the placeholder image when it is requested. On my local `Django` development server, I get the following error:

```
[17/Nov/2020 12:54:34] "GET /media/Images/placeholder.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2569
Not Found: /media/Images/placeholder.jpg
```

Why is this happening? The image `placeholder.jpg` exists, so how it can be that the file is not found ?

In the `LogCat` output of Android Studio, I get a similar error when I filter for okhttp. You can also see that the registration is done correctly but the file is not found:

```
2020-11-17 13:54:32.852 5825-5924/com.example.project D/OkHttp: {"response":"successfully authenticated.","id":1,"email":"abdullah@gmail.com","username":"abdullahc","profile_picture":"http://192.***.*.***:8000/media/Images/placeholder.jpg","date_joined":"2020-11-17T12:54:30.702559Z","token":"88b8ea2cf59ba851f7bac1751946213f5ee5afe9"}
2020-11-17 13:54:32.852 5825-5924/com.example.project D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (287-byte body)
2020-11-17 13:54:33.854 5825-5825/com.example.project I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.2.104:8000/media/Images/placeholder.jpg
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:102)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:56)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:164)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:154)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:62)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you save the following commands in settings.py ?

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Comment: I have set the MEDIA_ROOT because the file is in the media folder.

Comment: Add this in profile_picture next to default :- blank = True. AND check if this works and Tell me.